# Why is Regex VB.Net Dropping "-" When Getting Matches?

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex

Trying to parse this and return the following 3 items:

1. -30.25 31.46 -27.46 31.74
2. -24.57 32.03 -16.86 32.88
3. -13.82 33.19 -9.69 33.62

Using this regex expression below I get the matches, but drop the leading "-" at the front of each grouping.  I get the "-" in the middle of the group though.  Here is the expression I currently use.

```
Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\b\-{0,1}\d{1,2}\.{0,1}\d{0,2}\s{1}\-{0,1}\d{1,2}\.{0,1}\d{0,2}\s{1}\-{0,1}\d{1,2}\.{0,1}\d{0,2}\s{1}\-{0,1}\d{1,2}\.{0,1}\d{0,2}\b", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Thanks!

Here is the source text:
[Airports]

[Airways]

-30.25 31.46 -27.46 31.74

-24.57 32.03 -16.86 32.88

-13.82 33.19 -9.69 33.62

[Arcs]

Comment: seems your sample is broken; but what about just match those numbers as `(-?\d+\.\d+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\b will not match at the beginning of your input if the first character is a dash (-)

Comment: Glad to be of help!  Tell all your friends SO gave me the answer in 6 minutes! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your sample, try to use this: `(-?\d+\.\d+ ?){4}`